# How to Unit Test with ActionResult<T>?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit

I have a xUnit test like:

```
[Fact]
public async void GetLocationsCountAsync_WhenCalled_ReturnsLocationsCount()
{
    _locationsService.Setup(s => s.GetLocationsCountAsync("123")).ReturnsAsync(10);
    var controller = new LocationsController(_locationsService.Object, null)
    {
        ControllerContext = { HttpContext = SetupHttpContext().Object }
    };
    var actionResult = await controller.GetLocationsCountAsync();
    actionResult.Value.Should().Be(10);
    VerifyAll();
}
```

Source is

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the current number of locations for a user.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A <see cref="int"></see>.</returns>
/// <response code="200">The current number of locations.</response>
[HttpGet]
[Route("count")]
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> GetLocationsCountAsync()
{
    return Ok(await _locations.GetLocationsCountAsync(User.APropertyOfTheUser()));
}
```

The value of the result is null, causing my test to fail, but if you look at `ActionResult.Result.Value` (an internal property) it contains the expected resolved value.

See the following screen capture of the debugger.
[image]

How do I get the actionResult.Value to populate in a unit test?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

At run time your original code under test would still work because of the implicit conversion.

But based on the provided debugger image it looks like the test was asserting on the wrong property of the result.

So while changing the method under test allowed the test to pass, it would have worked when run live either way

`ActioResult<TValue>` has two properties that are set depending on what is returned from the action that uses it.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the <see cref="ActionResult"/>.
/// </summary>
public ActionResult Result { get; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets the value.
/// </summary>
public TValue Value { get; }
```

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ActionResultOfT.cs)

So when the controller action returned using `Ok()` it would set the `ActionResult<int>.Result` property of the action result via implicit conversion.

```
public static implicit operator ActionResult<TValue>(ActionResult result)
{
    return new ActionResult<TValue>(result);
}
```

But the test was asserting the `Value` property (refer to image in OP), which in this case was not being set.

Without having to modify the code under test to satisfy the test it could have accessed the `Result` property and make assertions on that value

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetLocationsCountAsync_WhenCalled_ReturnsLocationsCount() {
    //Arrange
    _locationsService
        .Setup(_ => _.GetLocationsCountAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(10);
    var controller = new LocationsController(_locationsService.Object, null) {
        ControllerContext = { HttpContext = SetupHttpContext().Object }
    };

    //Act
    var actionResult = await controller.GetLocationsCountAsync();

    //Assert
    var result = actionResult.Result as OkObjectResult;
    result.Should().NotBeNull();
    result.Value.Should().Be(10);

    VerifyAll();
}
```

Comment: Ok.   So it appears that either `ActionResult.Result` is populated or `ActionResult.Value` is populated but not both.  I didn't find that evident from the documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult-1?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @RichardCollette I doubt they would have made much mention of it as the object was really meant to be dealt with by the framework.

Answer (score 41):

The problem lies in the confusing interface of `ActionResult<T>` that was never designed to be used by us humans. As stated in other answers, `ActionResult<T>` has either its `Result` or `Value` property set but not both. When you return an `OkObjectResult` the framework populates the `Result` property. When you return an object the framework populates the `Value` property.

I created the following simple helper for my test library to help me test the return values when I am using `OkObjectResult Ok()` or other results inheriting from `ObjectResult`

```
private static T GetObjectResultContent<T>(ActionResult<T> result)
{
    return (T) ((ObjectResult) result.Result).Value;
}
```

This lets me do the following:

```
var actionResult = await controller.Get("foobar");
Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(actionResult.Result);
var resultObject = GetObjectResultContent<ObjectType>(actionResult);
Assert.Equal("foobar", resultObject.Id);
```

Comment: Nice. Can also be an extension method and used like this: `actionResult.GetObjectResultContent()`

Comment: Very helpful. Simple explanation and a great piece of helper code.

Comment: thanks so much for this. really nice and clean solution

Answer (score 22):

The issue is wrapping it in `Ok`. If you return the object itself, `Value` is populated correctly.

If you look at [Microsoft's examples in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2#actionresultt-type), they only use the controller methods for non-default responses like `NotFound`:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public ActionResult<Product> GetById(int id)
{
    if (!_repository.TryGetProduct(id, out var product))
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return product;
}
```

Comment: I was going to take issue with this answer since I didn't think it worked for async actions. Turns out that it works fine and my problem was that I returned a `Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Product>>>` and I had to reify (i.e. `.ToList()`) the collection first. +1 for you!

Answer (score 12):

As a continuation to the answer provided by @Nkosi and @Otto Teinonen,
there is an [implicit opertator](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ActionResultOfT.cs) to convert to/from `Value/Result`

Also, `ActionResult<TValue>` implement the interface `IConvertToActionResult`

```
  public sealed class ActionResult<TValue> : IConvertToActionResult
```

and provide `Convert` method that handle both `Result` and `Value` based on their null values, see the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ActionResultOfT.cs#L77) and return the non null value. Either `Result` or `Value` is set.

If the Controler didn't return `Ok(value)`, using `OkObjectResult` may return null and cause test fail, like:

```
 var result = actionResult.Result as OkObjectResult; //may be null
```

The next extension method handle both Result and Value and return the typed object T

```cs
public static T GetObjectResult<T>(this ActionResult<T> result)
        {
            if (result.Result != null)
                return (T)((ObjectResult)result.Result).Value;
            return result.Value;            
        }
```

Test case

```
[Test]
public async Task Test()
{
    var controller = new ProductsController(Repo);
    var result = await controller.GetProduct(1);
    await Repo.Received().GetProduct(1);
     //result.Result.Should().BeOfType<OkObjectResult>();  // may fail if controller didn't return Ok(value)
     result.GetObjectResult().ProductId.Should().Equals(1);
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Building on other answers, I think this is what you want...

```
var actionResult = await controller.GetLocationsCountAsync();
var okResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(actionResult.Result);
var value = Assert.IsType<int>(okResult.Value);
Assert.Equal(10, value);
```

**The desired `.Value` is inside the `OkObjectResult`**

My return type was `IEnumerable<MyClass>` so I used:

```
var values = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IEnumerable<MyClass>>(okResult.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be to serialize and then desalize in json type:

```cs
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    var controller = new ProductController();
    var result = controller.Products();
    var okResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
    if (okResult.Value == null) return;
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(okResult.Value);
    var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);
    if (values != null) Assert.Equal(1, values.Id);
}

private class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Route("api/product")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Products() => Ok(new { Id = 1, Name = "Smartphone" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NET 6, ControllerBase, ApiController and JsonResult<List>
I found this method helpful

```
public List<T> ActionResultToList<T>(ActionResult<IEnumerable<T>> response)
{
   return ((Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable<T>)
          ((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult)response.Result).Value)
          .ToList();

}
```

Then for List of `Product` as return value

```
var response = controller.GetList();
var list = ActionResultToList<Product>(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

This extension method might be useful:

```
public static class ActionResultExtensions
{
public static T ReturnValue<T>(this ActionResult<T> result)
    {
    return result.Result == null ? result.Value : (T)((ObjectResult)result.Result).Value;
    }
}
```

then you can use it like this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(response.ReturnValue<bool>());
```