# Get a Value from ActionResult<object> in a ASP.Net Core API Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, actionresult

I try to get a value from `ActionResult<object>` in an ASP.NET Core API method.

The API has a different controller. I try to use a method from controller B in controller A to return the result value. I get an `ActionResult` object from controller B. I can see the value with the debugger in the `ResultObject` but how can I get access to the result value in it?

```
public ActionResult<object> getSourceRowCounter(string sourcePath) //Method from Controller A
{
    var result = ControllerB.GetValue($"{sourcePath}.{rowCounterVariableName}");  
    var result2 = result.Value; //null
    var result3 = result.Result; //typ: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult} <-see Value=4 in it with Debugger
    //var result4 = result3.Value; //Error?!
    //var result5 = result3.Content; //Error?!
    //var result6 = result3.?????; //How can i get the Value = 4?
    return Ok(result); //should only return value 4 and not the whole object
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Unit Test with ActionResult<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489111/how-to-unit-test-with-actionresultt)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you're sure that it is a type of `OkObjectResult` then cast before using it like below:

```
var result3 = (OkObjectResult)result.Result; // <-- Cast is before using it.
var result4 = result3.Value; //<-- Then you'll get no error here.
```

Comment: How to handle this when instead of `OkObjectResult`, we have 4 different types, can we do this without cast?

Comment: You can also just cast to `ObjectResult` and still get `Value`, which can handle multiple result types, eg `OkObjectResult`, `UnauthorizedObjectResult`, etc.

Comment: In my case I had to cast it to `JsonResult` to get it to work.

Answer (score 23):

###### Suppose you have example function in `Repository.cs`:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<Todo>> GetTodosAsync() =>
   await _context.Todos.ToListAsync();
```

###### And function in `Controller.cs` looks like below:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Todo>>> GetTodosAsync() =>
    Ok(await _repository.GetTodosAsync());
```

###### Then in your `UnitTest.cs` you can get results by doing this:

```cs
var result = await controller.GetTodosAsync();
// list of todos is in `actual` variable
var actual = (result.Result as OkObjectResult).Value as IEnumerable<Todo>;
// or use `ObjectResult` instead of `OkObjectResult` for multiple types
```

Comment: Underrated comment!

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling an API from action and the API returns Ok(result) which you want to access in your action then below code can help you:

```
if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{                                   
    return Ok(response.Content); // returns API result
}
```